# Is there a class to hold a file (content and name)

Tags: java

I only want to be sure before creating it. Is there a class to "store" a file in java. In my case, I only need `name` and `content` (byte array?!).

Using Lombok it is as simple as this:

```
import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class Document {
    private String fileName;
    private byte[] content;
}
```

But I would prefer to use a "native" class if there is one.

Comment: I hope it isn't, because streams are so much better than byte[[

Comment: I would use a `File` instead of a `String` for the "filename"

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such class.

Comment: thanks for comments, i will stick to it. in my case i have some sources of binary data "ZipEntry"s and "File"s. I need an abstraction to just store name and content of both in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Your own class is fine.

```
public class Document {
    private String fileName;
    private byte[] content;

    public Document(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Document d = new Document("/path/to/file");
```

You should definitely consider whether you actually need the file name later on in the code or not, as it may be enough for you to use the content without a wrapping class.

Also note Java's IO provides many different ways to get the contents of a file - you are not limited to byte arrays. See [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) for a non-exhaustive list of file-related operations, including the [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) method to get a `Stream<String>` of all lines in a (text) file.

Comment: thanks for the hints. the files are of arbitrary content.